# How can I change background colors to the react element upon onclick event

Tags: css, reactjs

I've 3 react components which are basically 3 divs. Now I select one component out of them by clicking.now I want to change the selected component's background color to black. If I select another component then previously selected component should back to normal. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution:

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [bg, changeBGColor] = React.useState(1);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="box"
        onClick={() => changeBGColor(1)}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: bg === 1 ? "black" : "red"
        }}
      />
      <div
        className="box"
        onClick={() => changeBGColor(2)}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: bg === 2 ? "black" : "yellow"
        }}
      />
      <div
        className="box"
        onClick={() => changeBGColor(3)}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: bg === 3 ? "black" : "green"
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Paste this in a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) to see the output.

Here, I'm giving using a React hook which takes in a unique id. If it's set, then that component will be `black`.

So 1st `div` is `black` by default. If I click on 2nd `div`, I change the value of `bg` to `2` & in the `style` property I check if `2` is selected then set `black` color. Similarly, I do the same thing for 3rd div.

Answer (score 0):

assuming those components have their own unique properties (or you should add them) you can add modify their className like className={this.state.selectedComponent==="uniqueID" ? "activeClassName" : ""} while having a state property (selectedComponent) which is set to that unique property upon onClick

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class YourClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      color: 'black'
    }
    this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this)
    this.changeColor2 = this.changeColor2.bind(this)
  }

  changeColor() {
    this.setState({
      color: 'red'
    })
  }

  changeColor2() {
    this.setState({
      color: 'green'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }}>
        <button onClick={this.changeColor} />
        <button onClick={this.changeColor2} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is a very rudimentary way to do it, by default the div is black, when you click the first button you can change it to red and the second button to green

You can use this simple logic for several things